# How to create a Logic App from an existing OpenAPI 3.0 json file?

Tags: swagger, openapi, azure-logic-apps

I have an OpenAPI 3.0 JSON file that describes a simple API that exposes a couple of Get operations. I want to implement that API with an Azure Logic App.  Is there a native way in building the Logic App to generate the HTTP triggers from that OpenAPI JSON?

I know I can create custom connectors for my Logic App to consume other APIs but nothing obvious to me to generate/initialize my Logic App from a given OpenApi (or Swagger) file.

Given that my API definition is pretty simple with a couple of GET requests that accept a couple of parameters, I can easily manually create my HTTP triggers.  However, it seems like it would be beneficial as my API evolves to support more complex requests, that it would be nice to auto-generate my HTTP trigger(s) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-openapi-definition

#### Sample OpenAPI file

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: test api
  version: 1.0.0
  description: a test api for azure logic app
servers:
  - url: https://www.example.com/api/v1
tags:
  - name: Cars
    description: car tags
paths:
  /cars/{car-id}:
    summary: get cars by id
    description: a test endpoint
    get:
      tags:
        - Cars
      summary: this is the operation summary
      description: this is the operation description
      operationId: getCarById
      parameters:
        - name: car-id
          in: path
          schema:
            type: string
          required: true
        - name: accept
          in: header
          description: Accept header to indicate the acceptable response mediatype
          schema:
            type: string
          required: true
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  thing:
                    type: string
              examples:
                an_example_response:
                  description: an example
                  value:
                    thing: test
        "400":
          description: Bad Request
          content:
            application/problem+json:
              schema:
                description: Problem JSON as defined in
                  [RFC9457](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9457.html)
                type: object
                properties:
                  type:
                    description: The "type" member is a JSON string containing a URI reference [URI]
                      that identifies the problem type
                    type: string
                    format: uri-reference
                  status:
                    description: The "status" member is a JSON number indicating the HTTP status
                      code ([HTTP], <a
                      href="https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-15">Section
                      15</a>) generated by the origin server for this occurrence
                      of the problem.
                    type: number
                  title:
                    description: The "title" member is a JSON string containing a short,
                      human-readable summary of the problem type.
                    type: string
                  detail:
                    description: The "detail" member is a JSON string containing a human-readable
                      explanation specific to this occurrence of the problem.
                    type: string
                  instance:
                    description: The "instance" member is a JSON string containing a URI reference
                      that identifies the specific occurrence of the problem.
                    type: string
                    format: uri-reference
```

1. Create an Azure Logic App Custom Connector

[image: custom connector]

2. Open the new resource created, click `Edit` and then `import` OpenAPI description
   [image: add OpenAPI]
3. after the description is loaded, you can make any changes in the UI. Otherwise, click through the tabs for Security and Definition.
4. Click `Update Connector`
5. Then you can use your custom connector in Power Apps or a Logic App

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/use-custom-connector-flow

Comment: Thanks for your response Jeremy and sorry about the delay in getting back to you.  Seems I wasn't clear in my question but what I was asking for was a way to define http triggers in my Logic App, given an existing openAPI json file.  In other words, my Logic App is the one exposing the operations of that openAPI json file, it's not the one consuming those operations from another service.